# Getting two different date format using same query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select 
    CONVERT(varchar(10),logindatetime,103) 
from
    tClientLoginHistory 
where 
    ContactID = 1632016   
order by 
    ID desc 

select 
    CONVERT(varchar(10),'3/16/2015 12:00:00 AM ',103)
```

Result of 1st query:

```
16/03/2016
16/03/2016
23/07/2015
23/07/2015
14/05/2015
24/03/2015
16/12/2014
16/12/2014
11/12/2014
11/12/2014
```

Result of 2nd query:

```
3/16/2015
```

Why this mismatch?

Comment: `select CONVERT(varchar(10),'3/16/2015 12:00:00 AM ',103)` is saying "convert this string into a shorter string". Date formatting doesn't come into this query at all since at no point is a date(time) value present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `CAST` function to convert string to DateTime Type

```
select 
CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST('3/16/2015 12:00:00 AM ' AS DATETIME),103)
```